# Casting a loaded SWF as an interface

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, casting

I'm trying to load in a remote SWF and access it's methods and properties, using an interface. (There's a similar question here that got as far as "that's weird!" but didn't resolve it: [Loading swf and using it through interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465612/loading-swf-and-using-it-through-interface))

My remote SWF looks like this:

```
package 
{   
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.system.Security;

    import IMultiplayer;

    [SWF(width="238", height="60", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#FFFFFF")]
    public class Main extends Sprite implements IMultiplayer
    {
        public function init(e:Event):void
        {

        }

        public function TEST():void
        {
            trace("TEST()");
        }   
    }
}
```

I then have an interface that looks like this:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.*;

    public interface IMultiplayer
    {
        function init(e:Event):void;
        function TEST():void;
    }
}
```

And finally, I've got a loader class that pulls down the SWF and tries to cast it as the same interface that the remote SWF implements. EDIT - apologies for length, was asked to post the full source:

```
package uk.co.MyDomain
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.LoaderInfo;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.system.SecurityDomain;
    import flash.utils.Timer;

    import uk.co.MyDomain.*;

    import utils.Console;

    public class MultiplayerLoader extends Sprite
    {
        private var ld:Loader;
        private var _environment:String;
        public var _mpInstance:IMultiplayer;

        private const SANDBOX_SWF:String = "http://static.sandbox.dev.MyDomain.co.uk/smartfoxtest/dev/swf/MP.swf";

        public function MultiplayerLoader(environment:String)
        {
            _environment = environment;
        }

        public function loadMultiplayer():void
        {
            ld = new Loader();

            var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);

            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, multiplayerLoaded);
            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onLoadError);
            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOLoadError);
            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.DISK_ERROR, onDiskError);
            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, onNetworkError);
            ld.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.VERIFY_ERROR, onVerifyError);

            if(Security.sandboxType == Security.REMOTE)
            {
                trace('[MP Loader] Loading with context');
                ld.load(new URLRequest(SANDBOX_SWF), context);      
            }
            else
            {
                trace('[MP Loader] Loading with NO context');
                ld.load(new URLRequest(SANDBOX_SWF));   
            }
        }

        private function onIOLoadError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            notifyFailure('IOLoadError');
        }

        private function onDiskError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            notifyFailure('IOLoadError');
        }

        private function onNetworkError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            notifyFailure('IOLoadError');
        }

        private function onVerifyError(e:IOErrorEvent):void
        {
            notifyFailure('IOLoadError');
        }

        private function onLoadError(e:ErrorEvent):void
        {
            notifyFailure('IOLoadError');
        }

        private function multiplayerLoaded(e:Event):void
        {   
            var tester:IMultiplayer = e.currentTarget.content as IMultiplayer;          
            Console.log('Loaded: ' + tester);

            dispatchEvent(new MultiplayerEvent(MultiplayerEvent.SWF_LOAD_SUCCESS)); 
        }

        private function notifyFailure(reason:String):void
        {
            var failEvent:MultiplayerEvent = new MultiplayerEvent(MultiplayerEvent.SWF_LOAD_FAILURE);
            failEvent.params = {'reason':reason}

            dispatchEvent(failEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I DON'T cast it to use the interface, I can trace it out successfully and call functions (so e.target.content.TEST() will fire). However, as soon as I cast it to the interface, it fails.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

OK, I'm getting the same issue with a custom event class that's shared between both applications. Flash errors, saying it cannot convert from one class to the other - even though they're identical they're in different projects, and so I imagine different namespaces. I assumed that loading into the same applicationDomain would fix this, but it hasn't. Is there any other way I can get around this without resorting to a common library/SWC or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be an issue of the application domain. The loaded SWF resides in its own application domain so it does not share the exact same interface. Try to load the swf into the »current application domain«, using the `applicationDomain`property of the Loader's LoaderInfo Object.

look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html)

good luck…

EDIT::

it has to be done in the loaders load method

```
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("myButtons.swf"), context);
```

from [here](http://annafilina.com/blog/application-domain-and-external-swf-loading/)

EDIT 2::

Once I ran into an even more strange error, it was caused by the fact that i created an interface, compiled the »to load files« and »file that loaded«, changed the interface through adding a method and forgot to compile the »to load files« (there were a lot). Perhaps happened something like this…

EDIT 3::

If I remember right than one has to wait for the `Event.INIT` event of loaded swf's, first after this event the constructor of the loaded swf ran.

EDIT 4::

found [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html), perhaps you need to do:

```
var YourInterfaceClass:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition( "YourInterface" ) as Class; 
var myInstance:YourINterface = event.target.content as YourInterface;
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I have down. Doesn't work at all, as soon as I cast it to an interface it returns back to null. This is driving me absolutely nuts!

Comment: is the above code the complete code you use for loading? what is the error message?

Comment: The remote/interface examples are the complete ones, will update the post with the complete loader class now.

Comment: OK, added full source, edited out sensitive names for MyDomain. The URL in there is a sandbox, but this issue persists wherever I put the file (I've been testing remotely too)

Comment: i cannot see the import of »IMultiplayer« in the last source fragment and what is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I did a quick edit as I was leaving yesterday. The interface is imported and is identical to the one that the remote file uses. The error I get is a standard type coercion error: "cannot convert Main to IMultiplayer"

Comment: hmm… when I did this the last time I did not had the issues with the security sandbox, however if violated file wont load… I casted the loaded content like: Myinterface( loaded.content ), but that is just the same like the »as« syntax. The only difference i see right now is that i was using the Event.INIT event to listen for the load end. But if casting fails, this indicates that the two datatypes are not the same, in this case they may reside in different namespaces of application domains. You could try to put the IMultiplayer interface in a namespace diffrent from the default ns..

Comment: uhh… There seems to a difference in the casting methog, look here: http://upshots.org/actionscript-3/as3-casting-objects have not known this

Comment: Cast method is only one . Using "as" , second way is conversion . Anyway , You should check if Your "IMultiplayer" interface is same type as in loaded SWF , than You will know where is problem . Use code with "getDefinition" to compare this interfaces.

Comment: if I use "e.target.content as IMultiplayer" it doesn't fail at compile time, but returns null when I look at the object. If I use IMultiplayer(e.target.content) it fails when compiling, which is expected. I assumed the interface would be identical as it's literally the same interface file that gets compiled into remote and loader, but will look into it further. Thanks

Comment: Turns out it was related to both the applicationDomain, and also the fact that the Interfaces at either end had different packages despite being functionally identical. Working like a charm now, thanks for the assist!