# Cast loaded SWF with designed interface in main class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First of all I read linked topic but unfortunately any of the tips didn't work for me: [Casting a loaded SWF as an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343996/casting-a-loaded-swf-as-an-interface)

My problem indeed is similiar, I have got created SWF (Content.swf) where Content.as which is document class there:

```
package {   
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Content extends MovieClip implements IGame {

    public function igameMethod():void {
        trace("implemented method of IGame");
    }
}
```

}

IGame interface (in the same directory as Content.as) contains sole method 'igameMethod'

```
package  {
public interface IGame {
    function igameMethod():void;
}
```

}

and such compiled SWF is loaded by Loader class in LoadSWF where Main.as is document class and it is something like that:

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    private var swfLdr:Loader;
    private var game:IGame;

    public function Main():void {
        if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        swfLdr = new Loader();
        var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../lib/Content.swf");
        var defaultLoaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(true, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
        //none of settings for ApplicationDomain doesnt' work (with checkPolicy or with or without ApplicationDomain.currentDomain set)
        swfLdr.load(r,defaultLoaderContext);
        this.addChild(swfLdr);
        swfLdr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onExternalSWFLoaded);
        //tried Event.INIT too without success
    }

    private function onExternalSWFLoaded(e:Event) : void {
        var Game:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition( "IGame" ) as Class;
        if (e.target.content is IGame) {
            trace("Is IGame");
        }else {
            //output of this condition is false 
            //so e.target.content is not IGame
            trace("No its not IGame");
        }
        var Game:Class = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition( "IGame" ) as Class; 
        //tried to cast as class without success too
        var gameContent: IGame = IGame(swfLdr.content); //app breaks here
       // TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert LoaderSWF@87f0089 to IGame
    }
```

I've got also IGame interace (duplicated to LoadSWF project) with the same package structure (in the same folder as document class)  as Main.as to let LoadSWF use igameMethod() on Content.swf, but i can not use it because of TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert LoaderSWF@87f0089 to IGame. So the compiler can't convert this Content to IGame.

Have you got any idea, which would help me with this topic?
Thanks for any tips in advance.
Kindest regards Pawel

Comment: have you tried differentiating between your local `IGame` and the imported one? try putting it in a package and addressing with the specific package path, IE: `MyInterfaces.IGame`

Comment: Yes, I have tried that right now, again without a success. Still #1034. Checking it with describeType(swfLdr.content) gives me along other values in output xml this:    <method name="igameMethod" declaredBy="LoadSWF" returnType="void">
                <metadata name="__go_to_definition_help">
                  <arg key="pos" value="1281"/>
                </metadata>
              </method>  
and 
 <implementsInterface type="interfaces::IGame"/>

Comment: You did wrap your swf with a loaderSWF, unwrap it.

Comment: @BotMaster Could you elaborate your idea please? I don't quite understand what do you mean.

Comment: In publish settings choose merged into code or else you'll be set with a default preloader which wraps your swf and doesn't implement your interface. Btw the interface must be imported in your main project and not referenced by getDefinitionByName.

Comment: thanks. I use FlashDevelop I will try to play with including libraries today evening in home.
Kindest regards Pawel